# Can't post data to self because of design

Tags: php, javascript, html

i have a website that uses a number of containers (div's). In this scenario, we have three boxes down the left side and one bigger box on the right of these boxes. The bigger box on the right is the only thing that changes when a link is pressed, this is done with Javascript.

SO i have the index which is the main layout of the website and i also have the "pages" of the site, so when a link is pressed the main box (on the right) loads the new data.

On one of my pages i want to collect data and then run it through a PHP script that is in the head of the file, but when i click the button i realise it refreshes the whole page and it doesn't run the script on the page with the form.

Anyone had a problem like this, or know of something i could do to work around it?

I'm not really sure what code would be useful for helping me but if you need something just ask.

Thanks for the help

Comment: So you're using ajax to change page contents? You'd need some JS to intercept the post operation and redirect it to the appropriate sub-page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are loading all your content via JS already, you could just POST the form data via AJAX to a PHP script to process, then read the output and either provide an error message or remove the form from the page and show your success message.

How to approach your AJAX call is dependant on what you've used as a basis for the rest of your JS.
Personally I like to use the JQuery library, as it makes AJAX calls (and much more) very simple.

Answer (score 1):

How about you make the page design able to do it. Have the backend be able to spit out the state of the page when it posted.

Or use Ajax to post the data back and set the new state like you do already.